# S3 clone a bucket with all the permissions and options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

it is possible to grab one bucket and make an exact copy of the bucket permissions and attributes?

I have tried

`aws s3 sync`

But only copies the content, not the KMS key, and other attributes.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was raised 7 years ago and no AWS supported tool addresses your need (see [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/901) on github)
However, you can use other community tools, such as [s3s3mirror](https://github.com/cobbzilla/s3s3mirror/tree/2.1-stable). I am not sure that KMS key configuration will be synced too.